# xml to R dataframe, multiple layers of children

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I was trying to convert an xml into r df using XML package. Was able to get a df successfully, but whenever there were grandchildren under a child,  values of grandchildren was merged into one column.

Here is how the xml looks like:

```
<user>
    <created-at type="datetime">2012-12-20T18:32:20+00:00</created-at>
    <details></details>
    <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
    <last-login type="datetime">2017-06-22T16:52:11+01:00</last-login>
    <time-zone>Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</time-zone>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2017-06-22T21:00:47+01:00</updated-at>
    <is-verified type="boolean">true</is-verified>
    <groups type="array">
        <group>
            <created-at type="datetime">2015-02-09T09:34:41+00:00</created-at>
            <id type="integer">23215935</id>
            <is-active type="boolean">true</is-active>
            <name>Product Managers</name>
            <updated-at type="datetime">2015-02-09T09:34:41+00:00</updated-at>
        </group>
    </groups>
</user>
```

The code I used were:

```
users_xml = xmlTreeParse("users.xml")

top_users = xmlRoot(users_xml)

users = xmlSApply(top_users, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

The result I got had all the elements listed fine besides it combined everything under "groups" into one column. Is there anyway I can make each element under "group" a separate column in the final dataframe?

I also tried

```
nodes=getNodeSet(top_users, "//groups[@group]")
```

and

```
nodes=getNodeSet(top_users, "//groups/group[@group]")
```

and

```
nodes=getNodeSet(top_users, "//.groups/group[@group]")
```

and switched "top_users" to "user_xml", but each time got error message:

```
Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xC2 0x3C 0x2F 0x6E
```

Then tried

```
data.frame(t(xpathSApply(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("users.xml", useInternalNodes = T)),
                    "//user", function(y) xmlSApply(y, xmlValue))))
```

Which gave me the exact same thing as the first solution.

And finally, I tried

```
data.frame(t(xpathSApply(xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("users.xml", useInternalNodes = T)),
                    "//user/groups/group", function(y) xmlSApply(y, xmlValue))))
```

Which did give me a dataframe but only with elements in "group", and there is no way I can map it back to the first table I got that has all elements in "user".

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Consider column binding with `xmlToDataFrame()` of *user* children and *groups* children:

```
userdf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "/user"))
groupdf <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "/user/groups/group"))

df <- transform(cbind(userdf, groupdf), groups = NULL)   # REMOVE groups COL

df
#                  created.at details is.active                last.login                  time.zone
# 1 2012-12-20T18:32:20+00:00              true 2017-06-22T16:52:11+01:00 Pacific Time (US & Canada)
#                  updated.at is.verified              created.at.1       id is.active.1             name
# 1 2017-06-22T21:00:47+01:00        true 2015-02-09T09:34:41+00:00 23215935        true Product Managers
#                updated.at.1
# 1 2015-02-09T09:34:41+00:00
```